# Configure external m.2 SSD as removable drive in Windows 11

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, windows-11, storage

Installed a 1TB 22x80 M-key NVMe SSD into an external enclosure with a USB-C type connection. On Windows 11, created a GPT partition table and allocated the whole thing with an ExFAT partition, so I can move it around to Macbook and Linux as needed.

The drive does not appear as a removable USB drive, so unable to eject/dismount. I gather this is due to the drive type, or maybe the enclosure's circuit board presentation on the type.

What options are available for using m.2 SSDs as external and recognized as removable by the operating systems?  Even if it means using a different enclosure. The one I bought was maybe low-end, but I don't know.  SABRENT USB 3.2 10Gbps Type C Tool Free Enclosure for M.2 PCIe NVMe and SATA SSDs (EC-SNVE) with XPG SX8200 Pro 1TB m.2 2280 Gen 3x4 SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, even non-removable / fixed drives (as in, its SCSI Removable Medium Bit is 0) can be ejected (as in, "safely removed") in Windows, as long as Windows finds the drive to be "external" / "de facto removable" (e.g. the connection type being USB).

*(Note: I'm referring to the system tray icon only. It is normal that you don't see any eject button in Windows Explorer when RMB is 0, even when you have only one single partition / volume on the drive.)*

Most if not all HDD/SSD enclosures have SCSI RMB being 0, whereas thumb drives normally have SCSI RMB being 1, and for the record, RMB is not something that can be toggled by the user like SCSI Write Cache Enabled (WCE), as its not part of a mode page. (But certainly, you *can* change it by flashing a modified firmware or so, if you *can*.)

So it's more likely that the issue is some sort of hiccup in the specific installation you are using, which is not a rare thing when it comes to Windows. It can be due to some registry crap or bug in some vendor-made drivers. The bottom line is, I don't think the enclosure is the reason. I am not aware that one needs to report anything explicitly for Windows to identify it as "de facto removable".

I have some not so convenient alternatives for you. You can go to the `Settings -> Bluetooth & devices -> Devices`  and see if your enclosures are listed there and if so, see if you can "remove" it there. *AFAIK* it is equivalent to eject / safely remove.

[image]

[image]

Alternatively you can set the drive to Offline in Disk Management:

[image]

Which is even less convenient though, since you will need to set it to Online when you have the drive attached again.

---

I do NOT recommend changing the `Removal policy` of the drive to `Quick removal`, especially if it is some SATA SSD with volatile write cache in it, since it would significantly hurt write performance and might even cause greater write amplification. It might be more tolerable when your drive is an NVMe one though, especially if it's DRAM-less anyway.

(Also, in my experience, `Quick removal` does not always guarantee WCE to be set to 0. Sometimes the bit can be "out of sync" from the policy, but it could be some old-time bug that got fixed at some point.)

Comment: It was indeed present in the Bluetooth & devices | Devices | Sabrent, and the "Remove" option was available.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two alternatives:

- Make the drive act as a removable drive by turning off [write caching](https://www.iolosystem.com/resources/disk-write-caching.html). That allows the drive to be removed **if** it is not in the middle of a write operation.

  - Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, type *device manager*, and select *Device Manager*.
  - Right-click the external drive and select *Properties*.
  - On the *Policies* tab, ensure *Quick removal* is checked.
- If you prefer to use write-caching to improve disk I/O, then proceed as above, but select *Better performance*. In that case, as you mention, the drive should be safely ejected, committing to storage all pending writes.

  On occasion, the native Windows *Eject* button is *not* displayed in the Task Bar or Explorer. For safety, a third-party tool such as free [HotSwap!](http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/hotswap/) to safely eject hardware can be installed. My experience has been that these tools are a bit faster and more reliable, on some PC's, than the Windows *Eject* button.

[image: Device Manager - Disk Policies]

Answer (score -1):

It shouldn't make a big difference how it is treated. Only when you are pro, but then you would know the advantages and disadvantages.

Advice here is 1. remove safely the drive with icon from system tray 2. use tools like `sync64.exe -r` to write all data from cache to the drive before removing it.